# jQuery toggle working in one instance, but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly inexperienced with JS/Jquery in general, so this could be something simple I'm missing. I am trying to hide some text on a page, then enable it via a toggle link. This is the JS being used. The top one for "Attendence" works fine, but the one for "Description" does not hide nor toggle the text. I basically copy/pasted description from attendance, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".attend_list").hide();
        $(".attend_toggle").click(function()
        {
            $(this).parent().next('.attend_list').toggle();
        });

        $(".description_text").hide();
        $(".description_toggle").click(function()
        {
           $(this).parent().next('.description_text').toggle();
        });
});
</script>
```

This is the relevant HTML that is generated for each.

Attendance

```
<div id="attending10" class="membersAttending">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="membertoggle10">
        <p class="attend_toggle">
            <a href="#">Toggle Attendance</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="attend_list">
        test - Yes<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

Description

```
<div id="description10" class="description">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="descriptiontoggle10">
        <p class="description_toggle">
            <a href="#">Description</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="description_text">
        <p>Test</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle -> jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your HTML not your jQuery

You are missing a `</div>` and you have a paragraph inside a paragraph.

```
<div id="attending10" class="membersAttending">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="membertoggle10">
        <p class="attend_toggle">
            <a href="#">Toggle Attendance</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="attend_list">
        test - Yes<br />
    </p>
</div> <!--- this was missing -->
<div id="description10" class="description">
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="descriptiontoggle10">
        <p class="description_toggle">
            <a href="#">Description</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="description_text">
        Test <!--- this was a p in a p-->
    </p>
</div>
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/qLPEw/

Also (not part of the problem) if you create an event that does something to an element, and it needs actioning on load, trigger that event instead of writing more lines of jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".attend_toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next('.attend_list').toggle();
    }).click(); // trigger the bound function on load

    $(".description_toggle").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().next('.description_text').toggle();
    }).click(); // trigger the bound function on load
});
```

Though, I would hide those with CSS instead if they are meant to be hidden when the user first looks at the page.

Comment: Ah, that div was actually there, just missed it when copying the line. It seems the paragraph is what's breaking it. However, that data is coming from a WYSIWYG editor, which includes HTML in the text itself. Is there any way to work around that issue?

Comment: Yes, use `<div class="description_toggle">...</div>` instead

Comment: Ah thanks, that got it. Trying to fix up some rather hackey code for a community 'I'm part of as a side project. Leads to some interesting things.